# Split a JavaScript string into fixed-length pieces

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I would like to split a string into fixed-length (*N*, for example) pieces. Of course, last piece could be shorter, if original string's length is not multiple of *N*.

I need the fastest method to do it, but also the simplest to write. The way I have been doing it until now is the following:

```
var a = 'aaaabbbbccccee';
var b = [];
for(var i = 4; i < a.length; i += 4){ // length 4, for example
    b.push(a.slice(i-4, i));
}
b.push(a.slice(a.length - (4 - a.length % 4))); // last fragment
```

I think there must be a better way to do what I want. But I don't want extra modules or libraries, just simple JavaScript if it's possible.

Before ask, I have seen some solutions to resolve this problem using other languages, but they are not designed with JavaScript in mind.

Comment: Do you really write all that out everytime just to avoid a function call?

Comment: What makes you think that you can have fastest code execution _and_ simplicity of implementation? Those two qualities are often competing.

Comment: Here is another implementation, but still very similar to yours: http://phpjs.org/functions/str_split:530

Comment: @Esailija He said that somewhere? @sgmonda I don't think there is much better way. As javascript `string` does not have a method to do this, few lines of code like you have are fine. And this should be fast enough too.

Comment: Try using `String.substring` or `String.substr` instead of `String.slice` and comparing performance.

Comment: @Imp I don't know any other explanation for it needing to have a requirement to be easy to write other than writing it out every time. It wouldn't matter if it's very optimized but ugly code behind a function you just call.

Comment: I took the liberty to create a jsPerf test case with the proposed solutions. Your method is the fastest in Chrome and Firefox(at least) (about 50% faster than the next method). So always test and compare code. Shorter code is not automatically faster. http://jsperf.com/chunk-methods

Comment: Thank you, @FelixKling. Depending on the situation, we'll have to decide between efficiency or simplicity.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var a = 'aaaabbbbccccee';
var b = a.match(/(.{1,4})/g);
```

Comment: Very simple! I like it! But what happens if fixed-lenght is 32, for example? I would have to write `/(.{32}|.{31}|.{30}...|.{2}|.)/g`. Too text!

Comment: Even shorter: `a.match(/(.{1,4})/g);`

Comment: I'd probably use `[\S\s]` or similar over `.` as it includes every character

Comment: Perfect, @Niko! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry guys, I tried to edit this post before and write the same idea that @Niko had, but I don't know why, I couldn't

Comment: @sgmonda the {1,4} is a range, so it would be {1,32}. I think the resulting array has matches starting at [1] with [0] being the full string but I could be wrong.

Comment: Is it faster? Have you profiled it and compared it with the other approaches?

Comment: shorter version: a.match(/(.{3})/gy)

Answer (score 9):

See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456644/711085 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/8495740/711085 (See performance test in comments if performance is an issue.)

First (slower) link:

```
[].concat.apply([],
    a.split('').map(function(x,i){ return i%4 ? [] : a.slice(i,i+4) })
)
```

As a string prototype:

```
String.prototype.chunk = function(size) {
    return [].concat.apply([],
        this.split('').map(function(x,i){ return i%size ? [] : this.slice(i,i+size) }, this)
    )
}
```

Demo:

```
> '123412341234123412'.chunk(4)
["1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "12"]
```

Comment: Now that the regex answer does not require writing `/(.{32}|.{31}|.{30}............................|.{2}|.)/g`, I would have to recommend that answer since it very concise. =) This solution is better only for chunking arrays.

Comment: This seems perfect for the same problem but applied to arrays. Thank you! For spliting strings I prefer the above solution.

Comment: @FelixKling: Ah interesting. Though one should not take the test to imply (probably incorrectly) that Array.concat is slow. The most likely culprit is 1) the conversion to an array (testable by doing `.split('')` in preparation code), and 2) performing an unnecessary 4x if statements. Nevertheless the for-loop version is definitely going to be more efficient; I was undecided which of the two answers I should link. Thanks, I'll edit to point this out.

Answer (score 1):

```
function stringToChanks(string, chunkSize) {
    const chunks = [];
    while (string.length > 0) {
        chunks.push(string.substring(0, chunkSize));
        string = string.substring(chunkSize, string.length);
    }
    return chunks
}
```